# I need to define a casting constructor - a parameter that denotes the name of the document

Tags: c++, string, constructor

If it's not difficult, please tell me - I have a "Document" class, with following fields:

```
char * name 
char * subject
char * author
int page
int date
int time
```

In this class, I need to define a casting constructor - a parameter that denotes the name of the document.

1. Should my constructor take a string object and translate it into an enchant array?
2. Did I do the right thing ?

---

```
Document::Document( const string str ) { ctor type casting - accept an object of type string (document name)
name = new char[ str.length() + 1 ];  // then using c_str - returns an array of char type, terminated with zero
strcpy ( name , str.c_str() );       // After converting string to char - write it in the "name" field of the Document class
topic   = new char[1];               // For the rest of the char fields - allocate one byte of memory
author  = new char[1];
pages   = date = time = 0;            // Fields of type int - initialized with zeros
}
```

Comment: Please don't make up terminology, I've never heard of a "casting constructor"

Comment: How about using `std::string` instead of raw owning `char*`?

Comment: It is better to leave `topic` and `author` as `nullptr` instead of allocating a (useless) one-char buffer. Also, does your destructor clean up `name` again?

Comment: What is a _casting constructor_? What is an _enchant array_? (_enchant array_ == _char array_?)

Answer (score 3):

**Q:** Should my constructor take a string object and translate it into an char array (assuming an *enchant* array is actually a *char* array)?

**A:** Your code looks more or less correct, although you probably shouldn't use a char array in your class but just have `std::string`s. This will save you a lot of trouble.

**Q:** Did I do the right thing ?

**A:** Yes ans no, the code you show is more or less correct, but the general approach using arrays of char rather than `std::strings` looks wrong to me.

It'd do simply this:

```
class Document
{
  std::string name;
  std::string subject;
  std::string author;
  int pages;
  int date;
  int time;

public:
  Document(const std::string & str);
};

Document::Document(const std::string & str)
{
  name = str;
  pages = date = time = 0;
}
```

or better:

```
class Document
{
  std::string name;
  std::string subject;
  std::string author;
  int pages = 0;
  int date = 0;
  int time = 0;

public:
  Document(const std::string & str);
};

Document::Document(const std::string & str)
  : name(str)
{
}
```

Example of usage:

```
int main()
{
  Document foo("bar");
  ...
}
```

Comment: Pass by reference: `const std::string& str` (or by value + move: `Document(std::string str) : name(std::move(str)) {}`).